# Google Sign-in conflicts with Facebook login

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook-sdk-4.0, google-signin

I'm using [Google Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start?ver=swift) and [Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios) to provide Google and Facebook login in my app.

The problem is, when I'm using them both - **Facebook Login Screen (based on Safari View Controller) doesn't dismiss after user logged in.**

After hours of painful debugging I found out that the problem only appears if I initialise Google Sign-in before showing Facebook login prompt.

Basically, it's one line.

```
GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
```

If I comment that line - Facebook login works fine.

EDIT: This is what I have in my AppDelegate.swift:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
                                                                openURL: url,
                                                                sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as! String,
                                                                annotation: options [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
```

And the sad thing is that this method isn't invoked at all. 
But if I disable Google Login - it works fine.

Additional details:
I'm using Facebook SDK v4.12.0 and Google Sign-In SDK v4.0.0

Xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014), tested on iOS 9.3

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: When/where is that one line of code called?

Comment: it's called on app start (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) but after FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

Comment: In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function, return as follows:-         `return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)`

Comment: Which method isn't invoked? The `application...openURL` method? So if you put a breakpoint there it doesn't work?

Comment: Did you look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506832/conflict-between-facebook-sign-in-and-google-sign-in-ios)?

Comment: @tumber033 - yes, correct. The application...openURL method isn't invoked and I've found it out by putting a breakpoint there. Once I comment the line with GGLContext - then the application...openURL method is invoked.

Comment: @Tomer: yes, I did look at your link and there's no solution. they suggest to do changes to the `application...openURL` method which is not invoked at all in my case

Comment: @n0_quarter try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847848/facebook-and-google-login-conflict-xcode/36855497#36855497

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok folks, eventually I've figured it out. 
The trick which worked for me is to initialise Google Sign-In SDK **before** the Facebook SDK.

now my AppDelegate looks like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Initialize google sign-in
    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

    // init FB SDK
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

  return true
  }
```

Comment: thats what i done it in this answer which i commented http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847848/facebook-and-google-login-conflict-xcode/36855497#36855497 :)

Answer (score 8):

I am also using both google and facebook login and it is working fine.You have to use below method
 `func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool` as

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

       if url.absoluteString().containsString("FACEBOOK_ID") {
             return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
       }
       else {
           return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
       }
}
```

Comment: Please read edits to my question. the thing is, that the `application...openURL` method isn't invoked at all in my case. Once I comment the line with GGLContext - then the `application...openURL` method is invoked.

Comment: just try to return even for google as show in my answer.Currently u r only returning for facebook.

Comment: Ok, I've tried your solution and it didn't work. Facebook login prompt remains. Anyways, I don't understand how this possibly could work if the method `application...openURL ` isn't invoked at all

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented this code using the latest versions of Facebook and Google pods and **Swift 3.1** and it worked great!

```
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    if url.absoluteString.contains("facebook") {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: [:])
    } else {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                 sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                 annotation: [:])
    }
}
```

Comment: People keep suggesting this. It may be working code, but has nothing to do with my question. if you read my question, you'd notice that in my case the method application: open url: options: is not invoked at all.

Comment: You are using "openURL url: NSURL" in your code, and I'm providing a solution to people who stumble upon your question and are using Xcode 8 and Swift 3.1. I am not suggesting you implement my code with Xcode Version 7.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google documentation for the integration of their auth system, don't use this method :

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    var returnVal = false
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        returnVal = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    } else {
        returnVal = false
    }
    return returnVal
}
```

This is supposed to work for avoid conflicts with iOS 9, but as soon as i removed this, the fb log in worked and the google log in worked on an iOS 9 device too.

Hope this help anybody.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3 (iOs 10) just do like this: (it worked fine for me)

```
        func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

// FACEBOOK            
let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)

// GOOGLE
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                     sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                     annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
        return handled
    }
```

Comment: People keep suggesting this. It may be working code, but has nothing to do with my question. if you read my question, you'd notice that in my case the method application: open url: options: is not invoked at all.

Answer (score 0):

This worked on Swift 3: I had Facebook and Google Login in the same page.

```
 @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        print( " open URL : \(url.absoluteURL.absoluteString)")

        if url.absoluteURL.absoluteString.contains("fb728991920603705") //Facebook ID from Plist
        {
            print("contain FB ID")
            return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)

        }
        else {
            let result = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                           //added exclamation mark
                sourceApplication: String(describing: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication]!),
                annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
            return result
        }
    }
```

Comment: People keep suggesting this. It may be working code, but has nothing to do with my question. if you read my question, you'd notice that in my case the method application: open url: options: is not invoked at all.